# Why .filter predicate returns boolean and not any?

Tags: angular, rxjs

So i have the following code

```
let someValue = Observable.of([{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}, undefined, undefined]);
```

so now, if i want to filter undefined values, i either have to

```
someValue.filter(val => !!val) OR
someValue.filter(val => val !== undefined)
```

in TS, the .filter method returns typeof Any, so a filter method would work like

```
let someValue = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}, undefined, undefined];
someValue.filter(val => val)
```

and that would filter any objects that are undefined, so i was wondering why .filter in RxJS predicate is boolean instead of any?

Comment: You're asking why the callback for `filter` in RxJS (the "predicate" function) has to return boolean?

Comment: @martin yes why the predicate function has to return a boolean instead of any.

Comment: @bugs i meant the predicate for .filter has to be a boolean

Comment: @HassanA.Al-Rawi `someValue.filter(val => val)` is perfectly valid even if `someValue` is an Observable

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what you are actually filtering. To remove the `undefined` values from your array you should do: `someValue.pipe(map((v) => v.filter(val => !!val)));`

Comment: @bugs normally yes if you dont have strict ts linting, but if you have strict type linting, it will start to complain about different return types (boolean is not same as an object)

Comment: @benny_boe why would i need to pipe then map to filter ? i thought rxjs filter was enough to filter things  

e.g  
`someValue.filter(val => val !== undefined).subscribe(x => console.log(x));`

Comment: @HassanA.Al-Rawi Thats is RxJS5, RxJS6 syntax is different.

Comment: `someValue.filter(val => val !== undefined)` will just be `true` since `[...] !== undefine`. To claryfiy: You are not filtering your array, just the emitted values with this and your value is the array. ;-)
And yes this is the new syntax since rxjs 5.5

Comment: @benny_boe Correct i'm filtering the emitted values, and i think in RxJS5 just a map would be sufficient to filter values.
I guess i have to read about RxJS6

Comment: _"Why .filter predicate returns boolean"_ Because that's the definition of a predicate. _"in TS, the .filter method returns typeof Any"_ Because the ES language specification says that the return value must be coercible to a boolean and there is no explicit type for that.

Answer (score 0):

RxJS is probably having a strict typing in definition of `filter()`.

> - @param {function(value: T, index: number): **boolean**} predicate A
>     function that  * evaluates each value emitted by the source
>     Observable. If it returns `true`,  * the value is emitted, if `false`
>     the value is not passed to the output  * Observable. The `index`
>     parameter is the number `i` for the i-th source  * emission that has
>     happened since the subscription, starting from the number  * `0`.

you still can do

```
someValue.filter(Boolean)
```

which will filter out ***falsy*** values, which has the same effect as

```
someValue.filter(x => x)
```

Comment: Ok but if i have strict TS Linting, that would cause errors because of different typing
`argument of type any is not assignable to parameter of type boolean)`

Comment: Can you show the actual example where this typing error is shown?

Comment: `this.customer = this.customerService.getCustomer(this.custmerNum).filter(customer => customer);`

and getCustomer returns
`Observable<Customer | undefined>`

BTW im suing RxJS5

and the error im getting from linting
`TS2345: Type 'Customer | undefined' is not assugnable to type 'boolean'. Type undefined is not assignable to type 'boolean'`